# Correctly test Whole Number or N/A Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to test to see if a regular expression is a whole number or N/A however I cannot get my function to perform correctly. It always shows the error message.

```
function WholeNumberWithNA(field1) {
$("input:text[id*='" + field1 + "']").keyup(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var re = /^[0-9]{1,10}\|N\/A\|n\/a|N\/a|n\/A$/;
    var errormsg = "Whole Number or N/A only";
    var is_email = re.test(input.val());
    if (is_email) { input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid"); myFunction(event, errormsg); }
    else { input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid"); myFunction(event, errormsg); }
});

}

function myFunction(event, errormsg) {
    var element = $(event.currentTarget);
    var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
    var temp = event.currentTarget.parentElement;
    var error_element = $(".ValidatorIndicator", event.currentTarget.parentElement);
    if (!valid) { error_element.text(errormsg); error_free = false; }
    else { error_element.text(""); }
}
```

I think I realized my mistake. I got rid of the backward slashes that were in front on the "|" and it worked. Correct expression: /^[0-9]{1,10}|N/A|n/a|N/a|n/A$/

Comment: Post some examples of valid and invalid strings.

Comment: Use the `i` modifier to get case-insensitive matching, instead of listing all the different combinations.

Comment: @Barmar can you show an example please

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I think I found the solution see changes at top

Comment: @DeVonte you can make it even shorter. see answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regexp:

```
/^(?:\d{1,10}|n\/a)$/i
```

The grouping with parentheses is necessary so that `^` and `$` won't be attached to specific alternatives. The `i` modifier at the end makes it case-insensitive, so you don't have to list all different case combinations of `n` and `a`. And you shouldn't escape `|` if you want it to separate alternatives.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = /^(\d{1,10}|n\/a)$/i;
```

`\d` for digits.

Comment: The `^\d{1,10}|n\/a$` is incorrect as it will match strings like `1cvhhy---` and `fvuit785#^%$^n/a`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to allow untrimmed strings:

```
var pattern = /^\s*(\d{1,10}|n\/a)\s*$/i;

console.log(pattern.test("123456"));   // true
console.log(pattern.test("0.123456")); // false
console.log(pattern.test("n/A"));      // true
console.log(pattern.test("."));        // false
console.log(pattern.test("   7  "));   // true
```

Comment: welcome to SO. I think your aim was to make a code snippet. Learn how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)